# Summing two independent Markov Chains on a discrete-time and space environment

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have the following problem on my Stochastic Processes problem set:

> Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be two independent Markov Chains taking values on $I_{X}$ and $I_{Y}$ respectively, both countable sets. Also, let $(Z_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be iid random variables taking values on $\{0,1\}$. Now, define $W_n = X_n \mathbb{1}_{\{Z = 0\}} + Y_n \mathbb{1}_{\{Z = 1\}}$. Is $W_n$ a Markov Chain?

I understand that I have to show that

$\mathbb{P}(W_{n+1} = j| W_{n} = i, W_{n-1} = i_{n-1},..., W_0 = i_0) = \mathbb{P}(W_{n+1} = j| W_{n} = i)$,

for any states $j,i,i_{n-1}, ..., i_{0} \in I_{X}\cup I_{Y}$. I am stuck right now, but I have the impression that this result is false as stated.

For example, if $I_X$ and $I_Y$ were disjoint sets, observing that $W_n = i$ for some $i \in I_X$ gives me some information about $X_n$, although no information about $Y_n$. But if $i \in I_{X}\cup I_{Y}$, I can get "confused" since I cannot attribute this realization to one or another variable.

On the other hand, $Z_{n}$ is such a simple process and both $X_{n}$ and $X_{n}$ are Markov Chains, so the dependence on the past is somewhat limited.

I have no idea how to answer this question. I do know, however, that the sum of independent Markov Chains is not necessarily another Markov Chain, but I don't see how this result can help me here.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the case of disjoint $I_X$ and $I_Y$, and that's all you need. The question isn't asking whether $W_n$ *might* be a Markov chain under some circumstances (the answer is clearly yes, e.g. if $Z_n\equiv0$), but whether $W_n$ is *necessarily* a Markov chain, given the assumptions, so your counterexample is enough to disprove this. If $W_n\in I_X$, then it gives you no information about $Y_{n-1}$, but unless $Z_n\equiv0$ or $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of previous states, the next state $W_{n+1}$ depends on $Y_{n-1}$.

*Edit in response to the comment*:

A concrete counterexample is given by $Z_n$ uniformly distributed on $\{0,1\}$ and $X_n$ and $Y_n$ symmetric random walks on disjoint copies $\mathbb Z_X$ and $\mathbb Z_Y$ of $\mathbb Z$ starting at the respective origins at $n=0$. Assume that $Z_1=1$ and $Z_2=0$, so $W_1=y_1\in\mathbb Z_Y$ and $W_2=x_2\in\mathbb Z_X$. Now

$$P(W_3=a\mid W_1=y_1,W_2=x_2)=
\begin{cases}
\frac14&a\in\{y_1,x_2+1_X,x_2-1_X\}\\
\frac18&a\in\{y_1+2_Y,y_1-2_Y\}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

whereas e.g. $P(W_3=3_Y\mid W_2=x_2)=\frac1{16}$.

Comment: Thanks @joriki ! I agree with your view. However, could you help me construct a counter-example? I mean, formally. Thanks again!

Comment: @RaulGuarini: I added a concrete counterexample; hope that helps?

Comment: This helps a lot, @joriki! My only concern regarding your example is that shouldn’t we worry about the possibility of, for example, $y_1 +2 = x_2 + 1$?

Comment: @RaulGuarini: No, these are disjoint copies of $\mathbb Z$. That's why I labeled both the sets and the constants $1$, $2$, $3$ with the respective subscripts. We cannot have $y_1+2_Y=x_2+1_X$ because the two sides are elements of disjoint sets, $y_1+2_Y\in\mathbb Z_Y$ and $x_2+1_X\in\mathbb Z_X$. If you find this confusing, it might help to think of this as $\mathbb Z\times\{0,1\}$, with $\mathbb Z_X=\{(n,0)\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $\mathbb Z_Y=\{(n,1)\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and addition within each set defined via addition of the first elements of the tuples.

Comment: @RaulGuarini: Or, thinking of the random walk, think of it as two random walks on two disjoint lines, both labeled with the elements of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Oh, I think can see it now. You are supposing we observe the process $Z_n$, right? Then, let’s say we observe in a real world experiment $W_n =3$. Because we observe $Z_n$, we can say if it’s coming from the $X$ part or from the $Y$ part, right?

Comment: @RaulGuarini. No, there's no need to assume that we're observing $Z_n$. In fact we're not allowed to assume that, since $Z_n$ isn't included in any of the conditions of the conditional probabilities. But if $I_X$ and $I_Y$ are disjoint, there's no need to observe $Z_n$; the condition $W_k=i_k$ includes the information about $Z_k$, since $i_k\in I_X$ implies $Z_k=0$ and $i_k\in I_Y$ implies $Z_k=1$.